# Problem with foreach- loop

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

I would like to draw some circles and some squares and I would like to put in into a loop. But that does not seem to work. Any help would be great.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{xfp} % floating point unit f\"ur fpeval

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}

\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
      \edef\r{1.0}

         \draw circle (\r);
         \draw (-1.0*\r,\r) to (\r,\r); % oben
         \draw (-1.0*\r,-1.0*\r) to (1.0*\r,-1.0*\r); % unten
         \draw (-1.0*\r,0) to ["\fpeval{\r}"] (-1.0*\r,1.0*\r); % Mitte
         \draw (-1.0*\r,-1.0*\r) to (-1.0*\r,1.0*\r); % links
         \draw (1.0*\r,-1.0*\r) to (1.0*\r,1.0*\r); % rechts
         \pgfmathparse{sqrt(\r^2 + \r^2)}\edef\r{\pgfmathresult};

         \draw circle (\r);
         \draw (-1.0*\r,\r) to (\r,\r); % oben
         \draw (-1.0*\r,-1.0*\r) to (1.0*\r,-1.0*\r); % unten
         \draw (-1.0*\r,0) to ["\fpeval{\r}"] (-1.0*\r,1.0*\r); % Mitte
         \draw (-1.0*\r,-1.0*\r) to (-1.0*\r,1.0*\r); % links
         \draw (1.0*\r,-1.0*\r) to (1.0*\r,1.0*\r); % rechts
         \pgfmathparse{sqrt(\r^2 + \r^2)}\edef\r{\pgfmathresult};

         \draw circle (\r);
         \draw (-1.0*\r,\r) to (\r,\r); % oben
         \draw (-1.0*\r,-1.0*\r) to (1.0*\r,-1.0*\r); % unten
         \draw (-1.0*\r,0) to ["\fpeval{\r}"] (-1.0*\r,1.0*\r); % Mitte
         \draw (-1.0*\r,-1.0*\r) to (-1.0*\r,1.0*\r); % links
         \draw (1.0*\r,-1.0*\r) to (1.0*\r,1.0*\r); % rechts
         \pgfmathparse{sqrt(\r^2 + \r^2)}\edef\r{\pgfmathresult};

         \draw circle (\r);
         \draw (-1.0*\r,\r) to (\r,\r); % oben
         \draw (-1.0*\r,-1.0*\r) to (1.0*\r,-1.0*\r); % unten
         \draw (-1.0*\r,0) to ["\fpeval{\r}"] (-1.0*\r,1.0*\r); % Mitte
         \draw (-1.0*\r,-1.0*\r) to (-1.0*\r,1.0*\r); % links
         \draw (1.0*\r,-1.0*\r) to (1.0*\r,1.0*\r); % rechts
         \pgfmathparse{sqrt(\r^2 + \r^2)}\edef\r{\pgfmathresult};

         \draw circle (\r);
         \draw (-1.0*\r,\r) to (\r,\r); % oben
         \draw (-1.0*\r,-1.0*\r) to (1.0*\r,-1.0*\r); % unten
         \draw (-1.0*\r,0) to ["\fpeval{\r}"] (-1.0*\r,1.0*\r); % Mitte
         \draw (-1.0*\r,-1.0*\r) to (-1.0*\r,1.0*\r); % links
         \draw (1.0*\r,-1.0*\r) to (1.0*\r,1.0*\r); % rechts
         \pgfmathparse{sqrt(\r^2 + \r^2)}\edef\r{\pgfmathresult};

      \foreach \I in {1, ..., 5}{
         \draw circle (\r);
         \draw (-1.0*\r,\r) to (\r,\r); % oben
         \draw (-1.0*\r,-1.0*\r) to (1.0*\r,-1.0*\r); % unten
         \draw (-1.0*\r,0) to ["\fpeval{\r}"] (-1.0*\r,1.0*\r); % Mitte
         \draw (-1.0*\r,-1.0*\r) to (-1.0*\r,1.0*\r); % links
         \draw (1.0*\r,-1.0*\r) to (1.0*\r,1.0*\r); % rechts
         \pgfmathparse{sqrt(\r^2 + \r^2)}\edef\r{\pgfmathresult};
      }
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Assignments in the body of the `\foreach` loop are local. You'll need `\xdef` (which is `\global\edef`) or use the `evaluate` and the `remember` option of `\foreach`.

Comment: That sounds good. But to be honest, this is my first try with tikz. What do I have to do with evaluate and remember?

Comment: I just changed from edef to xdef. That seems to work. (Great) But does it also work with more similar figures?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With use of the `\pgfmathsetmacro`, nodes and labels above nodes (concept is quite similar to nice @Qrrbrbirlbel answer: +1):

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm, tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{xfp} % floating point unit f\"ur fpeval

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}
\usepackage{pgfmath}

\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}[
every label/.style = {font=\footnotesize}
                        ]
      \edef\r{1.0}
\foreach \i in {0,1,...,4}
{
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\R}{+sqrt(2)^\i*\r} %
\node[draw, minimum size=2*\R cm, label=\R] {};
\node[circle, draw, minimum size=2*\R cm] {};
}
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks al lot for your helpful hints.

Answer (score 8):

Assignments in the body of a `\foreach` loop are local. You can use make them global by using `\global\edef`/`\xdef`

```
\pgfmathparse{sqrt(\r^2 + \r^2)}\xdef\r{\pgfmathresult}
```

however this will destroy the original definition of `\r` (putting a [diacritic ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(diacritic)) on a letter). Even if you don't need that, I'd advise against it.

The `\foreach` macro offers much better options:

- the [`evaluate` key](https://tikz.dev/pgffor#pgf/foreach/evaluate) and
- the [`remember` key](https://tikz.dev/pgffor#pgf/foreach/remember).

In your case, you'll want something like this:

```
\foreach \I[
  evaluate={\nextR = \r * sqrt 2;},
  remember=\nextR as \r (initially 1)
] in {1, ..., 5}{
```

For every instance `\foreach` will evaluate `\r * sqrt 2` (equivalnt to your original `sqrt(\r^2+\r^2)`) and store it in `\nextR`, as if you've done

```
\pgfmathsetmacro\nextR{\r * sqrt 2}
```

and this evaluated `\nextR` will be the `\r` of the next loop, except for the first time where `\r` will be `1` (declared by using `(initially 1)`).

I've taken the liberty to draw the square using the [`rectangle` path operation](https://tikz.dev/tikz-paths#pgf.rectangle) ([alternative link](https://tikz.dev/tutorial#sec-2.6)) and using the modern syntax for specifying [the radius of a circle](https://tikz.dev/tutorial#sec-2.5) (`radius=…` instead of `(…)`).

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i[
  evaluate={\nextR = \r * sqrt 2;},
  remember=\nextR as \r (initially 1)
] in {1,...,10} {
\draw circle[radius=\r]
  (-\r, -\r) rectangle (\r,\r)
  node[left] at (-\r,.5*\r) {\pgfmathprintnumber{\r}}
  ;
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Off-topic: With the `through` and the `fit` library we can do `\node[draw,circle through=(0:1)](c){};\node[draw,fit=(c),inner sep=0pt](r){};\foreach\i in{1,...,10}{\node[draw,circle through=(r.north east)](c){};\node[draw,fit=(c),inner sep=0pt](r){};}`

Comment: Thanks al lot for your helpful hints.